# Is it possible to do a 'No Looking Right" run in Super Mario Bros?

Tags: super-mario-bros

This is something I found out just casually while playing Super Mario Brothers... (Super Mario All-Stars and NES)

"It all began on a dark night in Noah the Spike's bedroom. He was playing Super Mario Bros, waiting on his Pokémon GO to reset and spawn a new Pokémon on the map. Then, while playing, he thought,
"If one was to look left, hold right and down to cancel looking right, and jump, then it may be possible to not look right doing a run on this game. (Forced right looks excepted)"

That is what I thought and tested my theory that my brain came up with, and I was shocked at the fact that this worked. Later, I tested Mario All-Stars on my Wii Emulator and that worked too. But I have tried for hours to beat 1-3, the most troublesome, and no luck. Is there any record of this on YT that I just cannot find? Or is this just something that requires more patience?

Spots of Difficulty: Dashing only possible when there is so much land to jump with, movement only possible when one can jump, fear of running out of time until someone else discovers this glitch and records a run for YT.

Once again, **IS IT POSSIBLE**?

Comment: This seems very long. Can you shorten it?

Comment: @fasterthanlight The title makes for a pretty good TLDR.

Comment: @fasterthanlight This is the shortest way of putting it... sorry

Comment: Have you tried warping out of 1-2?

Comment: Tried that and found my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it is NOT possible to beat it this way, there is a livestream I made on YouTube for this and found a hole/abyss that I couldn't jump over and ended it. I think it was in 8-1 or 8-2.